# GPA data not available in API reponse

Tags: data-request, api, data.gov, uses-of-open-data, data

I have noticed a somewhere weird behaviour where I don't see any data related to GPA in API response, but it is available in the data dump. Anyone know how I can get the GPA from the API ?

Thanks in advance :D